# How can I unwind a collection, perform an operation, and reassemble the collection for each record in stream?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running a random walk algorithm to produce a temporal event chain. Each entry in the resulting collection is a node id. An example is:

```
[43116, 43116, 43116, 43116, 43116, 43116]
[61412, 61416, 4948, 61417, 61419, 61420]
...
```

For each row that's returned from the stream, how can I unwind the values, perform a algo.getNodeById(node_id) on that element, and pack those results back into a collection?

Cypher query is as follows:

```
CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(null, 5, 20, {
  nodeQuery: "MATCH (a:Asset) RETURN id(a) as id",
  relationshipQuery: "MATCH (a1:Asset)<-[:PATIENT]-(e1:EVENT)-[:NEXT]->(e2:EVENT)-[:PATIENT]-(a2:Asset) RETURN id(a1) as source, id(a2) as target",
  graph: "cypher" })
YIELD nodeIds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This second answer from me is based on the clarification in the comments to my first answer.)*

You can instead do this (using `algo.getNodesById()`, which takes a list of node IDs):

```
CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(null, 5, 20, {
  nodeQuery: "MATCH (a:Asset) RETURN id(a) as id",
  relationshipQuery: "MATCH (a1:Asset)<-[:PATIENT]-(e1:EVENT)-[:NEXT]->(e2:EVENT)-[:PATIENT]-(a2:Asset) RETURN id(a1) as source, id(a2) as target",
  graph: "cypher" })
YIELD nodeIds
UNWIND nodeIds AS nodeId
WITH DISTINCT nodeId
RETURN algo.getNodesById(COLLECT(nodeId)) AS nodes;
```

Or, you can do the same thing without `algo.getNodesById()`:

```
CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(null, 5, 20, {
  nodeQuery: "MATCH (a:Asset) RETURN id(a) as id",
  relationshipQuery: "MATCH (a1:Asset)<-[:PATIENT]-(e1:EVENT)-[:NEXT]->(e2:EVENT)-[:PATIENT]-(a2:Asset) RETURN id(a1) as source, id(a2) as target",
  graph: "cypher" })
YIELD nodeIds
UNWIND nodeIds AS nodeId
WITH DISTINCT nodeId
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = nodeId
RETURN COLLECT(n) AS nodes;
```

In both queries, the `WITH DISTINCT nodeId` clause is needed to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher does not delete a collection after `UNWIND` is executed on it. So, there is no need to recreate the collection.

For example:

```
WITH [61412, 61416, 4948, 61417, 61419, 61420] AS data
UNWIND data AS d
RETURN data, d;
```

returns this:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════╤═════╕
│"data"                              │"d"  │
╞════════════════════════════════════╪═════╡
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│61412│
├────────────────────────────────────┼─────┤
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│61416│
├────────────────────────────────────┼─────┤
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│4948 │
├────────────────────────────────────┼─────┤
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│61417│
├────────────────────────────────────┼─────┤
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│61419│
├────────────────────────────────────┼─────┤
│[61412,61416,4948,61417,61419,61420]│61420│
└────────────────────────────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Right, I think I understand that Cypher is not destroying the collection upon an UNWIND. I think the question I'm posing is: how would I perform my node lookup function for each element in "data" and return those values as a collection instead of a value in "d"?